# Data is not shown in created directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

My html looks like this:

```
<body ng-app="customDirective">
<div ng-controller="anController">
Date format: <input ng-model="fooData"> <hr/>
Current time is: <my-new-directive foo-Attr="{{fooData}}"></my-new-directive>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to update data inside of my created tag `my-new-directive` if a scope property `scope.fooData` is changed.

So I have a scope property called `fooData`:

```
$scope.fooData = 'Hello World!:)';
```

and I am creating a directive:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('customDirective', [])
  .controller('anController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.fooData = 'Hello World!:)';
  }])
  .directive('myNewDirective', [function() {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      var format,
          timeoutId;

      function updateValue() {
        element.text(format);
      }

      scope.$watch(scope.fooData, function(value) {
        format = value;
        updateValue();
      });
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link,
      scope: {
         fooAttr: '@' 
      }
    };
  }]);
  document.createElement('my-new-directive');
})(window.angular);
```

But if I write new values inside of input tag, then nothing occurs in my new directive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am using AngularJS 1.5.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several mistakes and the directive is overly complex.
On top of all comments above, this is wrong:

```
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link,
      scope: {
         fooAttr: '@' 
      }
    };
```

You restrict the directive to act when added as an attribute.
However in your example code:

```
Current time is: <my-new-directive foo-Attr="{{fooData}}"></my-new-directive>
```

You're using it as an element.

Change your directive like this:

```
   return {
      restrict: 'AE', // allow it as element or attribute
      link: link,
      scope: {
         fooAttr: '@' 
      }
    };
```

or

```
   return {
      restrict: 'E',  // only element
      link: link,
      scope: {
         fooAttr: '@' 
      }
    };
```

also, remove this:

```
  document.createElement('my-new-directive');
```

Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdjBZr
That should help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are my hero! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! it perfectly works! But why do you think that the directive is overly complex?

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes

1. Directive name should be `cammelCase`.
2. Attribute should `foo-attr` instead of `fooAttr`
3. As you had `@`(one way binding) you should use `foo-attr="{{fooData}}"`

Comment: I've used your corrections, however if I write to `<input ng-model="fooData">`, then nothing changes. Please, see my updated code in my question with your corrections. Is it correct place for `document.createElement('my-new-directive');`?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<div ng-anController="anController">
```

to

```
<div ng-controller="anController">
```

And try to follow better naming convension, like `app` name should not have `directive` suffix, and `directive` name also should be in `camelcase` as @pankajParkar mentioned.

Comment: Please, see my updated code in my question with your corrections. Is it correct place for `document.createElement('my-new-directive');`?

Answer (score 0):

1. `ng-anController="anController"`, it seems it should be `ng-controller="anController"`.
2. You should watch `scope.fooAttr` instead of `scope.fooData`.

Comment: why should see `scope.fooAttr` instead of `scope.fooData`?

Comment: You could have seen Roy''s codepen, in your directive, you did not know fooData, it is a isolate scope, you only get fooAttr, but `fooAttr` is bi-binding to `fooData`, so you could only watch `fooAttr`.